# Alamofire, error message Use of undeclared type 'GenericResponseSerializer'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I follow an alamofire/swift turorial by ray wanderlich and i use swift 2.0 and the alamofire 3.0 beta3. Now i have handled some minor issues but this one i am stuck with

```
  message: Use of undeclared type 'GenericResponseSerializer'
 Generic type 'Result' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)
```

and this is part of my code

```
extension Alamofire.Request {

    /** Response serializer for images from: http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial */
    class func imageResponseSerializer() -> GenericResponseSerializer<UIImage> {
        return GenericResponseSerializer { request, response, data in

            guard let validData = data else {
                let failureReason = "Data could not be serialized. Input data was nil."
                let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                return .Failure(data, error)
            }

            if let image = UIImage(data: validData, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale) {
                return Result<UIImage>.Success(image)
            }
            else {
                return .Failure(data, Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: "Unable to create image."))
            }

        }
    }

    /** Convenience method for returning images from: http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial */
    func responseImage(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<UIImage>) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(responseSerializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

ps: where/how can i download Alamofire 2.0 ??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)? Seems like a nice extension.
[Alamofire 2.0.2](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/releases/tag/2.0.2), but you should test to install via [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), really simple and clean tool.

Answer (score 1):

The example does not work with Alamofire 3.0. The `GenericResponseSerializer` logic has been heavily refactored. Please check out our latest README and 3.0 Migration Guide.

- [3.0 README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/3.0.0-beta.3#creating-a-custom-response-serializer)
- [3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

---

#### EDIT

Additionally, you should check out [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) which contains all the logic for response image serialization as well as many other cool features. It is also built by the AlamofireSF and will be well supported moving forwards.

Comment: Does AlamofireObjectMapper requires alamofire 2.0 only?

Comment: From what I can tell it looks that way. AlamofireObjectMapper is not an AlamofireSF supported library so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Got it working with the `ResponseSerializer`. Now no need to use ObjectMapper. Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

I for one don't fully understand the logic of the GenericResponseSerializer. So what I did for my app (because I do need this functionality) is just completely comment out the code that you just wrote in your post (I followed the same Ray Wenderlich tutorial as you) and then in my PhotoBrowserCollectionViewController, I changed things around a bit in my cellForItemAtIndexPath function. It looks like this now:

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell

    let imageURL = (photos.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PictureElement).imageURL

    cell.request?.cancel()

    // Using image cache system to make sure the table view works even when rapidly scrolling down the screen.
    if let image = self.imageCache.objectForKey(imageURL) as? UIImage {
        cell.imageView.image = image

    } else {

        cell.imageView.image = nil


        cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).responseImage { response in
            debugPrint(response)

            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            debugPrint(response.result)

            if let image = response.result.value {

                self.imageCache.setObject(response.result.value!, forKey: response.request!.URLString)
                cell.imageView.image = image
            } else {

            }


        }
}
return cell
```

Still haven't gotten it to fully work (because my API part doesn't work at all), so maybe this is completely wrong, but at least it builds. I used AlamofireImage for this, just using the basic explanations they have on their GitHub page, linked by the first guy who responded to this post. At least use that and see where it gets you.